# Grab link number reference from a page using Regex and JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex

If:

```
var obj=[6849,6850]
```

I need to grab these two numbers from the `href` attribute of a series of links on a page. The following code is grabing `6850`, but not `6849`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('a.title').each(function () {
    var links=jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
    if(links.indexOf('/')!=-1){
        i=1;
    }
    else{
        i=0;
    }
    var procura=links.match(/(\d+)/g)[i];
    if(obj.indexOf(procura)!=-1){
    ....
   }
};
});
});
```

How can I pass both numbers to `procura`?

EDIT: Updated code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('a.title').each(function () {
    var links=jQuery(this).attr('href'); 
    if(links.indexOf('/')!=-1){
        i=1;
    }
    else{
        i=0;
    }
    var procura=links.match(/(\d+)/g)[i];

    jQuery.each(obj,function(_,test) {
      jQuery.each(procura,function(_,match) {
        if(test.indexOf(match)!=-1){
            ...
        }
      });
    });

});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first thought it is because .match will return an array of found strings, but you knew that since you index yourself to the second if there is a slash

```js
document.write("1234sdfsf21312".match(/(\d+)/g))
```

So I believe you are looking for this - I made the obj strings otherwise they do not have an indexOf which is a string method.

```js
var obj=["6849","6850"];
$(function() {
  $('a.title').each(function () {
    var $link=$(this);
    var href=$link.attr('href'); 
    var idx = href.indexOf('/')!=-1?1:0; // choose the second one if slash
    var procura=href.match(/(\d+)/g)[idx];
    console.log(procura);
    $.each(obj,function(_,test) {
      if(test.indexOf(procura)!=-1) { // only works on strings 
        $link.attr("title",procura+" found"); 
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="title" href="/6850/blabla/6849.jpg">Link 1</a>
```

To get the last number change

```
    var idx = href.indexOf('/')!=-1?1:0; // choose the second one if slash
    var procura=href.match(/(\d+)/g)[idx];
```

to

```
    var matches=href.match(/(\d+)/g);
    var procura=matches.slice(-1).pop();
```

Comment: Please see update. You need to look through both arrays

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't working, see my edited code above.

Comment: I think you got it now. The problem still persists but I think it is related with not grabbing the numeric part of the URL (see my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090936/get-the-last-number-of-a-url-from-right-to-left) Thank you so much!

Comment: `var matches=href.match(/(\d+)/g);
 var procura=matches.slice(-1).pop();`