# Get the last number in a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How do I find the last number in a URL, from left to right?

For example:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/introducao-6849.html
```

Would return: `6849`

And:

```
https://www.portal-gestao.com/curso-modelos-negocio/1452-introducao/6850-melhores-praticas-no-uso-de-folhas-de-calculo.html
```

Would return: `6850`

This is what I'm trying:

**EDIT: Updated code**

```
jQuery('a.title').each(function () {
    var $link=jQuery(this);
    var href=$link.attr('href'); 
    var idx = href.indexOf('/')!=-1?1:0; // choose the second one if slash
    var procura=href.match(/(\d+)/g)[idx];

    jQuery.each(obj,function(_,test) {
        if(test.indexOf(procura)!=-1) { // only works on strings 
            ....
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the last number or just want to get it?

Comment: @Tushar just want to get it into procura

Comment: @Biffen Lol, yes, if it is the last you're right!

Comment: `'https://www.portal-gestao.com/curso-modelos-negocio/1452-introducao/6850-melhores-praticas-no-uso-de-folhas-de-calculo.html'.match(/.*[^\d](\d+)/)[1]` → `"6850"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general solution that would give you the last number in a string (not necessarily a URL)

```
function getLastNumberOfString(str){
  var allNumbers = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ' ').trim().split(/\s+/);
  return parseInt(allNumbers[allNumbers.length - 1], 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, since I'm passing a link to the function, perhaps I should convert it to a string first, right? I'm trying var href=$link.attr('href').innerText which isn't working

Comment: @NunoNogueira, but a link is a string already. You are trying to convert a string into a string ;) Just pass it to the function as is :``getLastNumberOfString( $link.attr('href') )``

Answer (score 6):

You can get the last number like following using `regex`.

```
function getLastNumber(url) {
    var matches = url.match(/\d+/g);
    return matches[matches.length - 1];
}

var url = 'https://www.portal-gestao.com/curso-modelos-negocio/1452-introducao/6850-melhores-praticas-no-uso-de-folhas-de-calculo.htm';
console.log(getLastNumber(url));
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the job, it gets you the last number in the `myString`:

```
var myString = "https://www.portal-gestao.685com/introducao-6849.html";
var myRegexp = /(\d+)\D*$/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```