# Get selected characters from a url

Tags: php

I need to retrive a selected part from a url . I've used **substr** method and i've successfully get the character. But my issue is that ,this is my sample url **localhost/xxxxxxx/sugar_daddy_member-1.xml** i need to retrive the last number in the url. By using this below given code i can sucessfully get the number but if two digit number comes in the url i can retrive only one number.

```
$page = 'sugar_daddy_member-10';
$last_char = substr($page, 19, 1);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the last number in a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090936/get-the-last-number-in-a-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `strrpos` function to find the dash.

```
<?php
 $page = 'sugar_daddy_member-10';
 $idx = strrpos($page, '-');
 $last_char = substr($page, $idx+1);
 echo ($last_char);
?>
```

Output

```
10
```

Comment: Is this a php frunction because when i use this returning this error. Call to undefined function rindex()

Comment: I used a perl function. Answer updated for php.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one using PHP `explode()` Function

```
<?php
$page = 'sugar_daddy_member-10';
$temp = explode("-",$page);
echo $temp[count($temp)-1];
?>
```